# Activity Monitor on 10.5.8 showing up blank

Tags: macos, mac, troubleshooting, osx-leopard

Just recently, out of the blue, any time I bring up Activity Monitor, there are zero processes listed. Also, any statistics on memory usage or disk activity are blank as well (including graph image). CPU reporting seems to be working okay.

I've run check disk with no problems reported, as well as repaired permissions.

Any idea what could be causing this?

**UPDATE**

After looking at my logs, I see this message:

```
9/28/10 10:59:35 AM [0x0-0x34034].com.apple.ActivityMonitor[2929] 2010-09-28 10:59:35.782 pmTool[17285:10b] Must be run as root
```

I double-checked the permissions on `/Applications/Utilities/Activity\ Monitor.app/Content/Resources/pmTool`:

```
-rwsr-xr-x   1 root  admin  119760 May 31  2008 pmTool
```

And for good measure, I tried running `sudo chmod u+s pmTool` to reset the SUID bit.

Still no change.

Comment: Anything interesting in the logs? View them using Console.app, then "All".

Comment: you didn't `chmod g+s`, might that make a difference?

Comment: Didn't make a difference. I've checked another Mac, and the permissions I posted above seem to be the correct ones. Thanks, though.

Comment: is something typed in the search bar in the activity monitor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about re-install the Activity Monitor using [Pacifist](http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract the application from the 10.5.8 pacakge?

Pacifist is a great app for inspecting packages, viewing files inside and extracting them as needed. Well worth the shareware fee of $20.

Answer (score 2):

Old topic but I had the same on Mavericks.

Then I clicked on one of the titles at the top like Process Name or % CPU and it works. Looks like Activity Monitor isn't populating the list until you sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Monitor is supposed to install in /Applications/Utilities, not /Applications.**

Do you have two copies installed? If so, try the one installed in Utilities. If it works, then delete the one in Applications.

If you have only one, then things are ... strange. You could try moving the app to Utilities and repairing permissions again.

** Both `/Library/Receipts/boms/com.apple.pkg.AdditionalEssentials.bom` and `/Library/Receipts/boms/com.apple.pkg.update.os.10.5.8.combo.bom` show the app installed in `/Applications/Utilities`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. It is installed in Utilities.

Comment: Oh, well, there goes that idea. I'll keep noodling on it ... turns out other people had much the same problem, but no one has posted a solution.

Comment: What about reinstalling ... using Pacifist (http://www.charlessoft.com/) to extract the app from the package?

Comment: Using Pacifist worked! Just reinstalled the app, and everything is normal now. Neat little program. FYI, if you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.